# What replaces plastic for microwave ready meals?

Tags: materials

In 2019, a divorced dad consumes cheap ready meals which come in plastic dishes, sealed at the top with transparent plastic film. Cooking instructions: Poke holes in the film with a fork, microwave for four minutes.

By 2024, single-use plastics are outlawed to reduce waste, harm to ocean wildlife, and reliance on fossil fuels. Our divorced dad demographic still wants cheap microwave ready meals, and the food industry does its best to meet that demand.

What material could microwave-safe ready meal packaging be made from?

Comment: How is this about worldbuilding?  And alternatives already exist.  Microwave-ready meals already come in wax-coated paper or pressed paperboard.  They can also be made of "mushrooms" though that isn't done for this yet.  Use foil instead of plastic at the top, remove it for the microwave and place a wet paper towel on top instead.  Done.

Comment: This appears to be a very IRL problem. If we knew the eventual answer, we sure wouldn't be sharing on worldbuilding.se but rather heading to the patent office or providing the data worldwide on an opensource network. If I didn't know any better, I would swear this was some sort of market research question :) the possibilities are numerous, most are still being developed fully in a cost effective and environmentally friendly way. For eg check out edible seaweed wrappers/containers.

Comment: 30 seconds on Google reveals that [marine biodegradable plastics](https://www.biofuelsdigest.com/bdigest/2018/08/18/marine-biodegradable-plastics-offer-hope-for-oceans-and-waterways/) are already in development and [biodegradable and compostable plastics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biodegradable_plastic) already exist. So, if you're looking for reality the answer is "better plastics."

Comment: While I'm not a divorced dad, I am a single male who occasionally uses a microwave to warm up leftovers.  (Though I actually use it more for the dog's meals than mine.)  Glass, ceramic, and reusable plastics (the dog dish is on its 3rd dog now) all work well.  But you really have two quite different questions: 1) what to do about the long-term non-viability of single-use plastic? 2) why are some segments of the population unable and/or unwilling to cook?.

Comment: @jamesqf people don't really cook because, like with streaming content vs physical media...convenience always trumps quality.  I'm with you.  I love to cook and aside from effort and learning, it is far more rewarding than a cheap burger made from almost food.

Comment: @Paul TIKI: I also read books :-)  Physical ones: the only ebooks I read are either programming manuals &c, or things from Project Gutenberg, where it's difficult to find physical copies.

Comment: @jamesqf Ahh, there is nothing like silence (or light classical at a low volume) and the feel of a paper volume in your hands for an excellent evening at home.

Answer (score 6):

#### Paper

I've bought microwave-safe meals that are in paper or thin cardboard trays.  They still use the same thin plastic film, but there is no reason they couldn't use paper there as well.

#### Reusable

Milk used to be delivered in glass bottles.  Full ones were exchanged for empties.

Microwave meals could arrive in reusable containers.  If plastic is completely banned, these could be glass or ceramic crockware.  Exchange them back after use so that they can be washed and reissued.